# Jenkins environment variables in project settings, how?

Tags: jenkins

In a Jenkins project you can set an arbitrary work path. I'd like to specify one below the standard project output path (e.g. workspace/my-project). However, for that I'd need to know the default path or at least the project name. There are a number of environment variables available (like $WORKSPACE), but I cannot use them in the project settings.

What is the correct way instead?

Comment: Which interpreter do you use to expand the environment variables?  The Windows Batch shell would expand names surrounded by percent sign as in %WORKSPACE%.

Comment: That's a pretty old question. Meanwhile I moved away from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

From Advanced Project Options, check **Use custom workspace**, and enter "./my-project" (without quotes)

Jenkins will accept relative paths in this field.  The help there states:

> If this path is relative, it's resolved against the "remote FS root"
>   directory of the slave, or $JENKINS_HOME on the master.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm already using. However, in order to avoid a hardcoded path I'd like to use variables here (e.g. the **$WORKSPACE** var contains the default path). Unfortunately, Jenkins doesn't seem to replace the vars on run, but instead creates a folder with name **$WORKSPACE**.